# drawerToggle not working right *Updated*

Tags: android

I have followed the documentation on the Developer page: https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html

Whats giving me an error is in the open/close event listener section.
It tells me that I am not putting in the right argument but I used the same one that was in the documentation.  I don't know what it's looking for.
I have the line that is giving me the issue marked with a comment line above it.
Thanks!

****UPDATE****
Expected Argument is:
android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar

Actual Argument is:
R.drawable.ic_drawer

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.gamescreen);

    //This is all stuff for the drawer
    player = createPlayer();
    sideMenu = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    menuList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.menu_list);
    //Now this is filling the drawer
    menuList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, menuString));
    menuList.setOnItemClickListener(new DrawerItemClickListener());
    //THIS IS WHERE THE PROBLEM IS. THE 3RD ARGUMENT 
    drawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, sideMenu, R.drawable.ic_drawer, R.string.drawer_open, R.string.drawer_close)
    {
        public void onDrawerClosed(View view)
        {
            super.onDrawerClosed(view);
            getActionBar().setTitle(drawerTitle);
            invalidateOptionsMenu();
        }
        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView)
        {
            super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
            getActionBar().setTitle(drawerTitle);
            invalidateOptionsMenu();
        }
    };
    sideMenu.setDrawerListener(drawerToggle);
}

@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
{
    boolean drawerOpen = sideMenu.isDrawerOpen(menuList);
    return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

Comment: Post the _exact_ error.

Comment: just updated. thanks

Comment: The tutorial seems to be targeting support library v4 but you've imported the v7 ActionBarDrawerToggle which has a different signature. You could change the import to make this work, but the docs say the v4 version is deprecated, not sure what to make of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check in your `res` if there is a `drawable` called `ic_drawer`. And check which resources you're importing.

Comment: Yes there is I put the file in there myself.